# Implementing generic event listerns in nopCommerce

Tags: asp.net-core, interface, nopcommerce

I'm trying to implement a system wide **generic** CRUD tracker that listens for CRUD operations

In nopCommerce, there are the following events:

```
EntityInsertedEvent<TEntity>
EntityUpdatedEvent<TEntity>
EntityDeletedEvent<TEntity>
```

which can be consumed by implementing the `IConsumer<EntityInsertedEvent<TEntity>>` interface.

IConsumer.cs

```
public interface IConsumer<T>
{
    void HandleEvent(T eventMessage);
}
```

Entity Inserted/Updated/Deleted Event.cs

```
public class EntityInsertedEvent<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    public EntityInsertedEvent(T entity);

    public T Entity { get; }
}
```

Standard implementation is: (only fires with BaseEntity)

```
public class EventConsumer :IConsumer<EntityInsertedEvent<BaseEntity>>
```

Attempts:

```
// compiles but there is a type mismatch between `BaseEntity` and the "EntityEvents"
public class MyConsumer<TEntity> :IConsumer<EntityInsertedEvent<TEntity>> where TEntity: BaseEntity

// does not compile because `TEntity` was not defined
public class MyConsumer :IConsumer<EntityInsertedEvent<TEntity>> where TEntity: BaseEntity
```

How should I implement `MyConsumer`?

Answer (score 0):

here an example for you. It's an consumer for OrderItem repository update event. If you want to generic event listener simply you can't register it dynamicly. Mediator pattern not work like this, so you have to give your class name before runtime.

```
public class OrderItemEventConsumer :
    IConsumer<EntityUpdatedEvent<OrderItem>>
{
    private readonly IOrderService _orderService;
    public OrderItemEventConsumer(IOrderService orderService)
    {
        _orderService = orderService;
    }

    #region Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Handle order item updated event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="eventMessage">Event message</param>
    public void HandleEvent(EntityUpdatedEvent<OrderItem> eventMessage)
    {
        
    }
    #endregion
}
```

The type of order item is BaseEntity.

```
public partial class OrderItem : BaseEntity
```